# How to make multiple edittext without too much code

Tags: android-studio

How do you add multiple edittext dynamically without knowing how many editext a user would need? I know how to add edittext by giving each edittext an id but if I don't know how many the user needs in the first place, how would I do this? I like to ask the user to enter the number of persons to a form and from there, display the number of edittext..... Just not sure where to begin on this..